# Consider the following functional which is as follows:

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am stuck on the following problem: [image]

I tried using Euler's formula which is as follows:   [image]

But my calculation gets complicated and I could not get the results. Can someone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What is the Euler-Lagrange equation you got?

Comment: The equation I get is: $3(1+y^2)y''-(y+2)(y')^2=0.$

Comment: Then a simple way of dealing with multiple choices is trial and error...

Comment: The answer key associated with the problem says that all of them are true. Can you please explain about how to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y(x),y'(x)):=\frac{1+y^2}{(y')^2}$. Then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2y}{(y')^2},$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'})=\frac{d}{dx}(-2\frac{1+y^2}{(y')^3})=
6\frac{(1+y^2)y^{''}}{(y')^4}-4\frac{yy'}{(y')^3};$$

The Euler Lagrange equations are then

$$y(y')^2-(1+y^2)y^{''}=0$$